# How Do i Check if a Certain Bot Exists in a Guild | discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Hey So I Have a Bot That Requires Two Bots to Work with each other I need to know How to Check if a bot is in the guild if not then to Tell the user to invite it.

Heres My Current Code:

```
if(message.guild.users.id === "ID") {
    //If its in the Server
} else {
    //If it isnt
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend fetching all members of a guild to ensure *all* members are cached. This will return a promise, resolve the promise to get the Collection of the Guild Members. Use `has()` with the bot's id, This will return true if the id was found in the Collection, false otherwise.

```
message.guild.members.fetch().then(memberList => {
   if (memberList.has("ID")) {
      // If it's in the server
   } else {
      // if it's not
   }
}).catch(console.error);
```

You can also try to fetch the bot directly and check if a GuildMember object returned.

```
message.guild.members.fetch("ID")
   .then(botObject => {
       // If found
    })
   .catch(err => {
      // If not found
   });
```

You will need to enable the GuildMember's Intent for fetching to work.